# Error occurs while importing excel file into MYSQL in php

Tags: php

I am new to php. I need to import excel details into MySQL database in php. I downloaded 2 files `reader.php` & `oleread.php` and save that under `wamp/www/folder`. When I execute the following code, the  server throw a error like

> The filename samp.xls is not readable

Give the solution to recover this problem. my code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Save Excel file details to the database</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
        include 'db_connection.php';
        include 'reader.php';
        $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    ?>
        <table border="1">
        <?php
            $excel->read('samp.xls');
            $x=2;
            while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
                $id = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1] : '';
                $name = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][2]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][2] : '';
                // Save details
                $sql_insert="INSERT INTO students (sid,name) VALUES ('$id','$name')";
                $result_insert = mysql_query($sql_insert) or die(mysql_error());
              $x++;
            }
        ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that your code is dangerous, what if name is `O'Hare`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while import excel file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772257/error-while-import-excel-file)

Comment: where is `samp.xls` do you have permission on it

Comment: What is the name of the Excel file you are trying to read? Where is it stored?

Comment: my excel file name is samp.xls, it stored under wamp/www/samp.xls

Comment: i got answer. i made a mistake in saving excel file extension. i saved as samp.xlsx. now save as to .xls.. i got answer.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The filename samp.xls is not readable

First thing to come to mind is that your php server cannot read your excel file ..

**WAMP** is on **Windows**, so Right-Click your excel file, and add `read` property to `Everyone`

Answer (score 0):

why not import it directly into phpmyadmin?? [click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diEwQk4uY14)